# How to go from one Screen to another by pressing Custom Drawer navigation Component in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

in my React-native project, I am using one **Custom drawer navigation**, in that drawer I am using three Items- **Home**, **All Notes**, **Make Notes**. As, it is customized drawer navigation I want to use one header and text at the bottom. The text component will be touchable and after pressing the text the Screen will navigate to another.

Here is the code of my Drawer navigation class-

```
let user_email ='', user_first_name='';

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null ,
  };

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
         <Icon name='menu'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

  <View style={{backgroundColor:"#ffff", height:'100%'}}>

       <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/header.jpeg')} style={{width: '100%', height: 150,  resizeMode:'cover', backgroundColor:"@aaaa"}}>  
       <Body style={styles.drawerBody}>
         <Image
           style={styles.drawerImage}
           source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/administrator-male.png'}}
         />
         <View style={styles.drawerHeaderText}>
           <Text style={{color:'#ffffff', fontSize:20, fontWeight:'400'}}>{user_email}</Text>
           <Text style={{color:'#ffffff', fontSize:16, fontWeight:'200'}}>{user_first_name}</Text>
         </View>

       </Body>
       </ImageBackground>

      <DrawerItems {...props} />

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={
        this.props.navigation.navigate('MakeNote')
      }>
        <Text>Screen 1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

   </View>

 );


const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: NoteMeHome,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),

  },
  ScreenInternal: {
    screen: ScreenInternal,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Screen With Navigation Drawer',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Second: {
    screen: MakeNote,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Create Note',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Third: {
    screen: AllNotes,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'All Notes',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',

      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon name='home' size={25}

        />
      )

    },
  },

  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Create Note',
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image  source={require('../assets/icon_create_note.png')}  
        style={{height:25, width:25,}}

        />
      )
    },
  },

  Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'All Notes',
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image  source={require('../assets/icon_all_notes.png')}  
        style={{height:25, width:25,}}

        />
      )
    },
  },

},

{
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}

);

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: Drawer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  DetailsNote: {
    screen: DetailsNote,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Details Note' },
  },

  UpdateNotes: {
    screen: UpdateNotes,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Update Note' },
  },

});


export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample, CustomDrawerContentComponent);
```

Now, when I run the project it is showing the following error-

[image]

If I remove the TouchableOpacity, then another error occurs & none of the drawer items are shown like below-

[image]

I want to show my three Drawer Items below the ImageBackground and One Text component below the drawer Items and by clicking the Text, I want to go to another screen.

So, I want to know what are the mistakes i am making and how to solve that.

Comment: Is the drawer navigation open normally? Is this an error when you press the button after it opens?

Comment: It shows he error by running the app, but if I remove the codes inside <TouchableOpacity> and <DrawerItems> then, it drawer opens normally but not showing the Items

Comment: Will removing only `touchableOpacity` result in the same error?

Comment: share the project repository.

Comment: @hongdevelop After removing the touchableOpacity, it shows the error given in the second image.

Comment: @devedv sorry I can't share the entire repository, but in the following link you will find the code of this particular class-
https://codeshare.io/29NvwM

Comment: Remove the `touchableOpacity`  and cover the <drawerItem> with the `<Content>`.

Comment: @hongdevelop I made the changes but still showing the error in second image.

Comment: you change header left  `headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        >
          <Icon name='menu'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),`